# Ruby - Iterate through each string inside an array and remove repeated characters

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, duplicates, iteration

I need to take out every duplicate from each string individually, but not from the whole array. Basically what I'm looking for is a `.uniq` for each string inside the array, but not the array as a whole.

Example:

```
array = ["abc", "abc", "xxzzyyww", "aaaaa"]
```

Expected output:

```
["abc", "abc", "xzyw", "a"]
```

I tried using `array.uniq` and `array.each.uniq` but they are not considering each string individually, they are checking if the string as a whole is a duplicate in the array, so it gives me the following output:

```
["abc", "ab", "xxzzyyww", "aaaaa"]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your example causes readers to think you are concerned with eliminating two identical characters in a row. If you want, say,  `"aaba"` to be converted to `"ab"` you should use a different example. In any event you need to edit to clarify your question.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland The question is pretty clear, when he says unique, that includes your given example as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input

```
array = ["abc", "abc", "xxzzyyww", "aaaaa"]
```

Code

```
p array.map { _1.chars.uniq.join }
```

Output

```
["abc", "abc", "xzyw", "a"]
```

Comment: Thank you! That one worked for evey single string in every array.  
By the way, what's the usage of the `_1` here? Is it just another way of saying `|x| x.` ?

Comment: Yes exactly. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

What about using `string#squeeze` (https://apidock.com/ruby/String/squeeze)

```
array = ["abc", "abc", "xxzzyyww", "aaaaa"]
# => ["abc", "abc", "xxzzyyww", "aaaaa"]

array.map {|x| x.squeeze }
# => ["abc", "abc", "xzyw", "a"]
```

Comment: Or simply: `array.map(&:squeeze)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked for the most part, but in one of the situations I had an array of strings that went like: 
`'qzbw qez xgedfibnyuhqsrazlwtpocj fxgpoqijdzybletckwaunsr'\
'pwnqsizrfcbyljexgouatd ljtperqsodghnufiycxwabzw'`

And for some reason it didn't got rid of every duplicate... Couldn't figure out why, tho. But replacing `.squeeze` with  `.chars.uniq` did the trick.